# Caching best practice for mobile hybrid/bridge app development

Tags: mobile-application, trigger.io, clientside-caching

I really need to limit any unnecessary network traffic and server trips.  Solution: common sense caching.  (I am not going to cache everything under the sun).

However, after reading through the [Caching Files](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/features/cache.html) documentation and implementing a couple of quick examples, **when** is the best time to cache an ajax json result?  Sure I can do the usual cache/no cache check each time my view is displayed.  But is there a way to perform an asynchronous load during initial application startup to prefetch remote data that I know the user is going to need?  Is using the [connectionStateChanged](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/event.html) event the only way (or closest way)?  Is there a way to "hook" into the splash screen (yes, I know Apple wants the splash screen for mostly transition)?  window.onload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you're looking for a way to asynchronously fetch remote resources once for each time the app starts up, and cache those data away?

Our [request module](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/request.html) is asynchronous by nature, so you could simply drop in a `forge.request.ajax` to start fetching an Ajax response, then store it away in the preferences module.

Although it's probably identical in practice, you could even wrap it in a setTimeout to make it even *more* asynchronous:

```
setTimeout(function ()
  forge.request.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/method.json',
    success: function (data) {
      forge.prefs.set("method.json-cache", data);
    }
  });
}, 10);
```

Comment: Yes, you are understanding me correctly.  Thanks for the input.